# Rails 4 has_many relation group by

Tags: has-many, relation

Guys how I can fixed this issue
I need to get the result of the relation and group the result using the user_id

My main loop something like that

```
<% if @users.count >0 %>
  <% @users.each do |user| %>
    <% if user.books.present? %>
      <% user.books.each do |book| %>  <!----this is the query I want to change---------->
        <% if book.user.present? %>
          id   | <%= book.user.id %>
          user | <%= book.user.user_name %>
        <% end %>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

I'm tried to used a lot of statements like

```
<% user.books.group_by(&:user_id).each do |book| %>
<% user.books.group_by(&:user_id).uniq.each do |book| %>
<% user.books.group_by(&:user_id).distinct().each do |book| %>
<% user.books.group_by{|us| us.user_id}.each do |book , us| %>
```

instead of the statement

```
<% user.books.each do |book|%>
```

but usually I get issues , so how i can group by array or DB relation in one statement ?

Comment: Just as a suggestion, the general thought in Rails and iOS programming is that if you're finding it difficult to do something you're likely doing in wrongly.  This means that you are probably fighting against the framework.  The code you have in there is pretty fragile.  For example, you are ripe for a "count called on nil object" error since you have no guarantee that @users will have a relation result in it.  What's wrong with users.books.each?  How is this not giving you the books grouped by user?

Comment: my checking only for disable any issues will appear  if the user didn't has any books

Answer (score 0):

If the issue is that you are experiencing "nil" call errors when you reference user.books.each, you might do this:

```
<% user.try(:books).each do |book| %>
```

This allows you to capture the error rather than fall through to the default error handler.

Otherwise, supposing that you have created a has_many and belongs_to relationship, you definitely ought to be using:

```
user.books.each {|b| }
```

This will give you books grouped by users.

Comment: my issue not to get nil , my issue how to get unique values from the query